# htaccess mod_gzip for SVG files

Tags: .htaccess, svg, gzip

I am trying to add gzip compression for my SVG files but it seem not to work, here is my code:

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|svg+xml|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

I tryed adding `svg` or `svg+xml` to `mod_gzip_item_include file`. But according to google pagespeed it is still not working. I also tryed to add `mod_gzip_item_include mime ^image/.svg`. I think the exclude all images is blocking the gzip of the SVG.